# Merge [plottable.js] into [plottable]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

Could we merge [plottable.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plottable.js) into [plottable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plottable)? The two tags are both used to refer to the [Plottable.js](https://github.com/palantir/plottable) charting library. Both tags are used about the same amount - keeping [plottable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plottable) is preferred by the project maintainers.

Comment: Did the project maintainers mention their preferred tag somewhere?

Comment: @approxiblue I asked them in person, I work with them :)

Comment: If the project/library is named "Plottable.js" (as it apparently is), why in the world would the maintainers prefer the [plottable] tag? The best tags are specific and unambiguous. A generic name like [plottable] doesn't fit that description. I'd personally prefer [plottable.js].

Comment: Hey all! I'm one of the maintainers. Just opened this ticket
https://github.com/palantir/plottable/issues/3147

Answer (score 3):

On Stack Overflow, we prefer to use tags that are named to match the official name of the product/library/tool/language. When I first saw this request, it seemed to me that the official name of the library was "Plottable.js", which would argue that the tag should be named [plottable.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plottable.js), as it originally was.

However, I see that [the maintainers would prefer](https://github.com/palantir/plottable/issues/3147) that the primary tag name be [plottable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plottable). In the words of Calvin Fernandez:

> We'd like to merge the "plottable.js" tag into the "plottable" tag. Our github repo is `/palantir/plottable`, and our npm package is called "plottable" and it makes sense to maintain naming consistency in Stack Overflow as well.

Given that clear and compelling evidence of naming consistency, I've gone ahead and made [plottable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plottable) the primary tag. The older tag, [plottable.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plottable.js), is a synonym of it. No bookmarks or anything else should break with this change. I've also made a few improvements to the tag wiki, but it could use some more love from a maintainer or expert.